# How to set query bands in teradatasql lib?

Tags: python, teradata, teradatasql

I was using this [teradata module](https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module) and then I've changed to this [new one](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql).

The fact is, in the old one, it was easy to set queryband by setting queryBands parameter in `udaExec.connect` function. In this new module I was not able to find a simple way to set querybands as easy as in the old module.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Build a string with`SET QUERY_BAND='name1=value1;name2=value2;...;nameN=valueN;' FOR SESSION` statement and pass that to `.execute`.

Comment: I did this, I thought that could be a simpler way as in the old module, but I realize that this new module doesn't have the same dictionary approach for query_band neither a log to file feature

Comment: True, _teradatasql_ is strictly a driver. It doesn't include the wrapper with additional "DevOps features"  in section 2 of the  _teradata_ package document you linked above..

Comment: I think you can gather your comments and write an answer. You've explained everything possible related to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *teradatasql* package is strictly a driver. It doesn't include the wrapper with additional "DevOps features" listed in section 2 of the *teradata* (*udaExec*) package document you linked above.

You need to build a string with a `SET QUERY_BAND='name1=value1;name2=value2;...;nameN=valueN;' FOR SESSION` statement and pass that to `.execute`.

You could build that statement from a dictionary like *tdodbc* does, but there won't be any entries pre-populated (like ApplicationName, Version, ClientUser, etc.); you'd have to add those yourself if you want them.

```
c.execute("SET QUERY_BAND = '{};' FOR SESSION".format(";".join("{}={}".format(k,v) for k, v in queryBands.items())))
```